# Inserting a new child element, assign the parent's value to another new element in xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, bash, file, command-line-interface, xmlstarlet

I gave the following element in an xml file:

```
<xml>
 <title> Testing the tittle of the file </title>
</xml>
```

I want to write a xmlstarlet that transforms it to

```
<xml>
<title><p> Testing the tittle of the file </p></title>
<subtitle><p> Testing the tittle of the file </p></subtitle>
</xml>
```

I have tried the following in cli:

```
xmlstartlet ed -L -s //xml/title -t elem -n p  $1
```

Nothing happens. Need help.

- Ofuuzo

Answer (score 0):

Using `xmlstarlet`:

Extract the existing title text into a variable:

```
title=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/xml/title" src.xml)
```

Delete the existing title node and build the required new XML by piping `xmlstarlet ed...` commands to one another.  You can redirect the output to a temporary file and then move it to your source XML file `mv new.xml src.xml`

```
xmlstarlet ed -d "//xml/title" src.xml |
xmlstarlet ed -s "//xml" -t elem -n title -v "" |
xmlstarlet ed -s "//xml/title" -t elem -n p -v "$title" |
xmlstarlet ed -s "//xml" -t elem -n subtitle -v "" |
xmlstarlet ed -s "//xml/subtitle" -t elem -n p -v "$title"
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml>
  <title>
    <p> Testing the tittle of the file </p>
  </title>
  <subtitle>
    <p> Testing the tittle of the file </p>
  </subtitle>
</xml>
```

Another option is to use `xmlstarlet tr` to perform an `xslt` transform.  Again, you can capture the transformed xml in a temporary file and then mv/rename it to your source xml file:

```
xmlstarlet tr t.xslt src.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <xml>
  <title>
    <p> Testing the tittle of the file </p>
  </title>
  <subtitle>
    <p> Testing the tittle of the file </p>
  </subtitle>
</xml>
```

Contents of src.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml>
  <title> Testing the tittle of the file </title>
</xml>
```

Contents of t.xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/xml/title">
<xml>
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}"><p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p></xsl:element>
    <subtitle><p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p></subtitle>
</xml>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```